# Symmetric and exterior powers of a projective (flat) module are projective (flat)

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Assume that $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $P$ a projective (flat) $R$-module. Why $\mathrm{Sym}^n(P)$ and $\Lambda^n(P)$ are projective (flat) for every $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using the fact that projective modules are direct summands of free modules. Suppose $P\oplus Q\cong R^k$. Then $$R^{k^n}=(P\oplus Q)^{\otimes n}=P^{\otimes n}\oplus\cdots ,$$ so $P^{\otimes n}$ is projective. But then notice that $\Lambda^n(P)$ and $\mathrm{Sym}^n(P)$ are both direct summands of $P^{\otimes n}$.

Edit: As Darij Grinburg points out, and I only just now noticed, this only works for some rings $R$, such as $\mathbb Q$ algebras.

Comment: I guess that for the flat case you use the fact that a direct summand of a flat module is flat, am I right?

Comment: @Chris: sorry, I didn't mention the flat case. Yes, you can argue that a direct summand of a flat module is flat and use the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: Dear @GrumpyParsnip If $P$ is just flat, how is the argument altered? It won't in general be a summand of a free module anymore... Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Assume $F$ flat, the symmetric and exterior powers are always direct summands of $F^{\otimes n}$ and that is flat.

Comment: @rschwieb: Chris has it right. $F^{\otimes n}$ is flat by a direct argument.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Mainly I just wanted to bring that half of the argument to the surface for future readers. Thanks!

Comment: Why are $\wedge^n P$ and $\mathrm{Sym}^n P$ direct summands of $P^{\otimes n}$ ? I know they are if $R$ is a $\mathbb Q$-algebra, but in the general case?

Answer (score 9):

As Darij remarked in his comment, if $R$ is not a ${\mathbb Q}$-algebra one cannot argue that $\bigwedge^n P$ and ${\mathfrak S}^n P$ are summands of $P^{\otimes n}$, thereby reducing the statement to showing that projectivity and flatness are stable under taking tensor powers. Instead, one might argue as follows:

1. *Freeness:* If $F$ is a free $R$-module on with basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, then $\bigwedge^k F$ is free over $\{v_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge v_{i_k}\ |\ i_1<\ldots<i_k\}$ and ${\mathfrak S}^n F$ is free over $\{v_{i_1}\cdots v_{i_k}\ |\ i_1\leq \ldots\leq i_k\}$. The same holds for a possibly infinitely generated free module $F\cong R^{(I)}$ if $I$ is equipped with a linear order.

   > *Side question:* What if we do not impose $\textsf{AC}$? Are $\bigwedge^n R^{(I)}$ and ${\mathfrak S}^n R^{(I)}$ still free then?
2. *Projectivity:* The projective modules are the summands/retracts of free modules. Since $\bigwedge^n(-)$ and ${\mathfrak S}^n(-)$ preserve retracts (as does any functor) and freeness, they therefore also preserve projectivity.
3. *Flatness:* The flat modules are the direct limits of finite rank free modules. Since and $\bigwedge^n(-)$ and ${\mathfrak S}^n(-)$ preserve direct limits and finite rank free modules, they therefore also preserve flatness.

Comment: Dear @Hanno, Do you know some reference for the functorial properties (preservation of direct limits and finite rank free modules) of the symmetric and exterior power functors?